# Is there an R package which provides API to use the Bcurvestrip function from bloomberg excel add-in

Tags: r, bloomberg

The Bloomberg Excel Add in has this function called BCurveStrip where I can input spot rates for various tenors and I can create a curve object which I can use to compute forward rates. Is there any R package which helps me with an API to user that in an R code?
I have come across RBLPAPI package but that package doesnt have an equivalent function for BCurveStrip.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is only available as a premium service within their enterprise risk offering (MARS API).

You may have noticed that most important curves like SOFR, ESTR etc anyhow don't work in excel as well. This is because it's all behind a paywall.

If you are interested, you can always reach out to your Bloomberg rep.

Comment: Ultimately, this really is a question for the help desk though.